# Android app crashes on few real devices but works fine on an emulator which has the same API as that of the real device

Tags: android, android-studio

Android app crashes on few real devices but works fine on an emulator which has the same API as that of the real device.

In build file I have given target sdk as 24 and minimum sdk is 14.
Also the real device is located remotely so I can't even do usb debugging.

Comment: anyway you have to get a stacktrace of the crash. You can do using Google Analytics, or some other things like ACRA

Comment: I tried to save the exception stack strace in file but even file is not created in that devices.

Comment: Even tried to save the logcat in file

Comment: Can you add the log stack strace.

Comment: file is not getting savec in device and also the device is located remotely

Comment: Use Crashlytics or a similar service to receive stacktraces. If you cannot update that remote device with a newer version (the one with Crashlytics in it), you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use fabric.io Crashlytics to log crash and find the problem.

http://try.crashlytics.com/